# How to create a new dataframe with filtered conditions?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am having a hard time creating a new data frame with the filtered conditions I've implemented. I've been able to figure out how to actually filter the data, but for some reason when I go to create a new subset with subset() it always says there's an unexpected symbol? I've tried a couple of different methods to mitigate the issue but nothing seems to work.

I have a column called "Admitted/Not Admitted", and I'm trying to eliminate every data point with the condition "Not Admitted". I was able to filter the data set using the function:

```
X2022_Releases_Data_1__no_NA[X2022_Releases_Data_1__no_NA$`Admitted/Not Admitted`== 'Not Admitted',]
```

with X2022_Releases_Data_1_no_NA being the name of my data set. I want to eliminate all of these data points from my data set so I can work within these parameters, creating a new data frame in my global environment without any of the values I filtered with the above command. What should I do?

Comment: Save the result to a new variable `filtered <- X2022_Releases_Data_1__no_NA[X2022_Releases_Data_1__no_NA$\`Admitted/Not Admitted\`!= 'Not Admitted',]`. Or using subset `filtered <- subset(X2022_Releases_Data_1__no_NA, \`Admitted/Not Admitted\`!= 'Not Admitted')`. In the future it's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show the code you tried that threw errors.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! I think I may have been missing some punctuation or something, because the code I tried was pretty similar to this. Very helpful!